# Grab data from website HTML table and transfer to Google Sheets using App-Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-parsing

Ok, I know there are similar questions out there to mine, but so far I have yet to find any answers that work for me. What I am trying to do is gather data from an entire HTML table on the web (https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/indiana/2022-gamelogs.html) and then parse it/transfer it to a range in my Google Sheet. The code below is probably the closest thing I've found so far because at least it doesn't error out, but it will only find one string or value, not the whole table. I've found other answers where they use xmlservice.parse, however that doesn't work for me, I believe because the HTML format has issues that it can't parse. Does anyone have an idea of how to edit what I have below, or a whole new idea that may work for this website?

```
function SAMPLE() {
  const url="http://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/indiana/2022-gamelogs.html#sgl-basic?"
  // Get all the static HTML text of the website
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}).getContentText();
  // Find the index of the string of the parameter we are searching for 
  index = res.search("td class");
  // create a substring to only get the right number values ignoring all the HTML tags and classes
  sub = res.substring(index+92,index+102);

  Logger.log(sub);
  return sub;
}
```

I understand that I can use importHTML natively in a Google Sheet, and that's what I'm currently doing. However I am doing this for over 350 webpage tables, and iterating through each one to load it and then copy the value to another sheet. App Script bogs down quite a bit when it is repeatedly waiting on Sheets to load an importHTMl and then grab some data and do it all over again on another url. I apologize for any formatting issues in this post or things I've done wrong, this is my first time posting here.

**Edit:** ok, I've found a method that works, but it's still much slower than I would like, because it is using Drive API to create a document with the HTML data and then parse and create an array from there. The Drive.Files.Insert line is the most time consuming part. Anyone have an idea of how to make this quicker? It may not seem that slow to you right now, but when I need to do this 350 times, it adds up.

```
function parseTablesFromHTML() {
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/indiana/2022-gamelogs.html");
  var docId = Drive.Files.insert(
    { title: "temporalDocument", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS },
    html.getBlob()
  ).id;
  var tables = DocumentApp.openById(docId)
    .getBody()
    .getTables();
  var res = tables.map(function(table) {
    var values = [];
    for (var row = 0; row < table.getNumRows(); row++) {
      var temp = [];
      var cols = table.getRow(row);
      for (var col = 0; col < cols.getNumCells(); col++) {
        temp.push(cols.getCell(col).getText());
      }
      values.push(temp);
    }
    return values;
  });
  Drive.Files.remove(docId);
  var range=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Test").getRange(3,6,res[0].length,res[0][0].length);
  range.setValues(res[0]);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution by formula

Try

```
=importhtml(url,"table",1)
```

[image]

### Other solution by script

```
function importTableHTML() {
  var url = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/indiana/2022-gamelogs.html'
  var html = '<table' + UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}).getContentText().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm,"").match(/(?<=\<table).*(?=\<\/table)/g) + '</table>';
  var trs = [...html.matchAll(/<tr[\s\S\w]+?<\/tr>/g)];
  var data = [];
  for (var i=0;i<trs.length;i++){
    var tds = [...trs[i][0].matchAll(/<(td|th)[\s\S\w]+?<\/(td|th)>/g)];
    var prov = [];
    for (var j=0;j<tds.length;j++){
      donnee=tds[j][0].match(/(?<=\>).*(?=\<\/)/g)[0];
      prov.push(stripTags(donnee));
    }
    data.push(prov);
  }
  return(data);
}
function stripTags(body) {
  var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
  return body.replace(regex,"");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Right, I know I can do that, as I mentioned at the bottom of my post. "I understand that I can use importHTML natively in a Google Sheet, and that's what I'm currently doing. However I am doing this for over 350 webpage tables, and iterating through each one to load it and then copy the value to another sheet. App Script bogs down quite a bit when it is repeatedly waiting on Sheets to load an importHTMl and then grab some data and do it all over again on another url." I am looking for a way to speed up my process by accessing this data in the script itself, rather than using importhtml.

Comment: ok, see the other solution that works fine!

Comment: Wow, that is awesome! I am pretty new to coding, and so half of what you did went over my head, but I'm trying to figure it out so I can learn. haha Thank you so much. I am only having one minor issue, and that's when a team's name has a "&" in it, Like Texas A&M.  In those cases the result array outputs "Texas A&ampM" instead. I'm trying to figure out how filter that out at the moment with a replace, but so far hasn't worked. Regardless, thank you and this is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: so try `donnee=tds[j][0].match(/(?<=\>).*(?=\<\/)/g)[0].replace(/&amp;/g,'&').replace(/&nbsp;/g,' ');`